# What is xid in facebook comment api?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to put facebook comment in my wordpress blog for each post. I want to pass the url of the post as an xid but it doesn't work. I want to do that so that i will be able to collect the comments for each post separately.

Let me know if there is any other way to collect the comments for post separately.

Comment: have you tried to use the test console on the fb:comments page to test your settings http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct to use the XID as a unique identifier for each post.  According to the documentation, the XID can consist of: "alphanumeric characters (Aa-Zz, 0-9), hyphens (-), percent (%), period (.), and underscores (_)".

Instead of using the URL, try passing in the unique ID of each post if you have access to it from WordPress.  If that isn't an option, use PHP to url-encode your URL.

Comment: my page url is like www.site.com/definition/[post-title].html and everytime [post-title] is unique. But when I tried to use [post-title] as XID the comment box doesnt even appear in the page. I am not sure but, is there a restriction on the length for XID?